# Delete from table where id=@id in gridview giving error

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to delete data of selected row in gridview but I am getting error like this

> "Must declare the scalar variable "@ModelID"."

here's my code of sqldataadapter

```
 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:myconnectionstring %>' SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [ChannelsDataValidation] WHERE ([ModelID] = @ModelID)" DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM ChannelsDataValidation WHERE (ModelID = @ModelID)" UpdateCommand="UPDATE ChannelsDataValidation SET ChannelNumber = @ChannelNumber, DataType = @DataType, MinValue = @MinValue, MaxValue = @MaxValue, Unit = @Unit, Name = @Name WHERE (ModelID = @ModelID)">
    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="ModelID"></asp:Parameter>
    </DeleteParameters>
```

Comment: Once you have [ModelID] and two times you have ModelId without square braces. I am not an expert, but this couldn't generate an error?

Comment: **PLEASE** tell me this code is not in your ASP page? Very vulnerable code, if so!

Comment: Are you ever giving the ModelID parameter a value?

Comment: @j.f. nope.it gives error when clicking the delete button on gridview

Comment: So it would probably make sense to give it a value then, right?

Comment: @GeoffJames it was automatically generated by sqldataadapter

Comment: @j.f. thats why i am using parametrized object. it should take value from column of gridview. but for some reason it is giving error

Comment: OK, but we cannot see how you have that setup. Do you have your `DataKeyNames` setup properly?